# Include path in filename when creating a pdf

Tags: python, django, rest

I have a script which let to generate a PDF file and then send it to another application (LogicalDOC) in order to save it.

I'm getting a problem with `payload` line. The filename should be my filename variable but it doesn't take account.

If I write `filename.pdf`, I find filename.pdf in LogicalDOC with the good content.

But filename have to change automatically for each new BirthCertificate.

How I can pass the path as filename ?

This is my script :

```
@login_required
def BirthCertificate_PDF(request, id) :

    birthcertificate = get_object_or_404(BirthCertificate, pk=id)

    data = {"birthcertificate" : birthcertificate}

    template = get_template('BC_raw.html')
    html  = template.render(Context(data))


    filename_directory = str(BirthCertificate.objects.get(pk=id).lastname.encode('utf-8')) + "_" + str(BirthCertificate.objects.get(pk=id).firstname.encode('utf-8')) + "_" + str(BirthCertificate.objects.get(pk=id).birthday)
    filename = 'Acte_Naissance_' + filename_directory + '.pdf'
    path = '/Users/valentinjungbluth/Desktop/Django/Individus/' + filename

    file = open(path, "w+b")
    pisaStatus = pisa.CreatePDF(html.encode('utf-8'), dest=file, encoding='utf-8')

    file.seek(0)
    pdf = file.read()
    if pdf :

        payload = '{ "language":"fr","fileName":filename,"folderId":3309569 }'
        upfile = path
        files = { 
        'document': (None, payload, 'application/json'),
        'content': (os.path.basename(upfile), open(upfile, 'rb'), 'application/octet-stream')
        } 
        url = 'http://localhost:8080/services/rest/document/create'
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
        r = requests.post(url, files=files, headers=headers, auth=('admin', 'admin'))

        context = {"birthcertificate":birthcertificate,
                   "path":path}

        return render(request, 'BC_PDF.html', context)
    file.close()

    return HttpResponse(pdf, 'application/pdf')
```

If I wrote :

- `"FileName":"test.pdf"` I obtain the test.pdf file in logicalDoc (see picture)
- `"FileName":"filename"` I obtain the filename file with unknown format in logicalDoc (see picture)

I would like to get my `filename variable` as document name

[image]

Comment: I filled a form with some informations : lastname, age, sex, ... and I create a pdf file which takes all data from my form. Then, this pdf file is saved on my server and I want to import this document in LogicalDOC. The filename which is given to my file in LogicalDOC should be the same than saving filename on my server. Apparently, `FileName` takes only something like : `try.pdf` and not path :/

Comment: If I understood correctly you could use format: `payload = '{{ "language":"fr","fileName":{0},"folderId":3309569 }}'.format(filename)`. Now `payload` variable will contains filename. Is it what you need?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner Sorry it doesn't work. I would like to get as filename in LogicalDoc the filename variable. For example : `Acte_Naissance_Test_Muriel_2011-09-11.pdf` as I wrote the filename variable. `{0}` doesn't work. It seems that `fileName` doesn't take account variable :/

Comment: @neverwalkaloner It works if I write the line as : `payload = '{{ "language":"fr","fileName":"{0}","folderId":3309569 }}'.format(filename) ` Thank you ! Maybe write my edit as an answer and I will accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string formatting for this. Just do follow:

```
payload = '{{ "language":"fr","fileName":"{0}","folderId":3309569 }}'.format(filename)
```

Comment: Thank you ! As I suggested, it missed `" "` around `{0}`